# accessing pandas data a million times -need to improve efficiency

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am a biologist trying to validate an experiment. In my experiment, I have found 71 mutations after a particular treatment. To determine if these mutations are truly due to my treatment, I want to compare them to a set of randomly generated mutations. It was suggested to me that I might try to generate a million sets of 71 random mutations for statistical comparison.

To start with, I have a dataframe with the 7000 genes in the genome of interest. I know their start and end positions. The first five rows of the dataframe look like this:

```
    transcript_id   protein_id  start   end kogClass
0   g2.t1   695054  1   1999    Replication, recombination and repair 
1   g3.t1   630170  2000    3056    General function prediction only 
2   g5.t1   695056  3057    4087    Signal transduction mechanisms 
3   g6.t1   671982  4088    5183    N/A
4   g7.t1   671985  5184    8001    Chromatin structure and dynamics
```

Now about the million sets of 71 random mutations: I have written a function that I call a million times and it seems not to be very efficient because after 4 hours it was only 1/10 of the way through. Here is my code. If anyone can suggest a way to speed things up I would owe you a beer! And my appreciation.

```
def get_71_random_genes(df, outfile):
    # how many nucleotides are there in all transcripts?
    end_pos_last_gene = df.iloc[-1,3]

    # this loop will go 71 times
    for i in range(71):
        # generate a number from 1 to the end of all transcripts
        random_number = randint(1, end_pos_last_gene)
        # this is the boolean condition - checks which gene a random number falls within 
        mask = (df['start'] <= random_number) & (df['end'] >= random_number)
        # collect the rows that match
        data = df.loc[mask]
        # write data to file.
        data.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: One big factor is probably `data.to_csv()`: you're opening and closing a file 71,000,000 times, and as I/O is one of the slowest operations, I'm guessing this is a huge bottleneck.

Comment: That makes sense. What is a better way? build a massive df with 71,000,000 rows and then write that to a file? I assume my poor laptop will crash. Maybe a dictionary?

Comment: A quick fix would just be to call `to_csv` after the loop, instead of within it. That’s a 71x reduction in I/O. Definitely you don’t want a 71e6 Pandas column, that’s a recipe for disaster. :( I would say, store what you can in a Numpy array, and perhaps every 10,000 sets then write out the array and flush it.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga - for the most part each row is a unique gene. But there are some genes with multiple "kogClass" annotations and the boolean mask returns multiple rows. Each random_number is meant to simulate a single nucleotide polymorphism, or a change in one character of the DNA sequence. And the mask is meant to find the gene range to which that sequence belongs. Perhaps it would be best to drop the duplicate genes and just select 71 random rows? How would you recommend doing that? I am a beginner, so please, explain!

Comment: @sm544 I've added an answer that does just that. Although, I suppose if you are trying to simulate a SNP then you *do* want to sample positions, because genes will not have the same probability of being selected, given random SNPs

Comment: @sm544 I'll think about it some more, given that idea. Maybe `pandas` is't the best data-structure, but we'll see...

Comment: @sm544 how big of a read are we talking about, i.e. what's `min(start)` and `max(stop)`? Probably best way to do it is to just fill a list from 1 - 0 with the row indices and sample from that list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The generation of a random number will be important to simulate a random SNP due to the fact that genes that are longer (ie, have more nucleotides) should have a higher chance of being mutated than a shorter gene. min(start) is 1 and max(stop) is 13968614. I would like to hear what other data structures you might have in mind.

Comment: @sm544 yeah, then I think I see a solution that will be valid yet still performant. I'll sketch it out in a bit, but essentially, you map a `numpy.ndarray` to gene number, and sample from that array. numpy will make this relatively easy.

Comment: @sm544 alright, I've added the sketch to my answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! The updated version takes into account the size of each gene and is even faster than the first version on my setup. Youre the best.

Comment: @sm544 out of curiosity, what was the final time?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the first version was about an hour, the second version was about 15 minutes.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at Julia (the ‘modern Fortran’) if speed is still an issue. It’s syntax is a mixture of Matlab and Python, and its speed approaches C. It has a package DataFrames which is nearly identical to Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that all the following does:

```
for i in range(71):
    # generate a number from 1 to the end of all transcripts
    random_number = randint(1, end_pos_last_gene)
    # this is the boolean condition - checks which gene a random number falls within 
    mask = (df['start'] <= random_number) & (df['end'] >= random_number)
    # collect the rows that match
    data = df.loc[mask]
    # write data to file.
    data.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Is select 71 random rows from the data-frame without replacement. Note, this is taking **forever** because each time you do

```
(df['start'] <= random_number) & (df['end'] >= random_number)
```

You iterate through the entire data-frame *three times*, and then an additional time when you do:

```
data = df.loc[mask]
```

This is an incredibly inefficient way to sample rows. You could do this much more efficiently by randomly sampling 71 indices, then using those indices directly on the data-frame (which would not require even a single full pass over the data-frame). But you don't need to do that, `pd.DataFrame` objects *already implement an efficient sample method*, so observe:

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10, 10)), columns=["c%d"%d for d in range(10)])

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9
0  13   0  19   5   6  17   5  14   5  15
1   2   4   0  16  19  11  16   3  11   1
2  18   3   1  18  12   9  13   2  18  12
3   2   6  14  12   1   2  19  16   0  14
4  17   5   6  13   7  15  10  18  13   8
5   7  19  18   3   1  11  14   6  13  16
6  13   5  11   0   2  15   7  11   0   2
7   0  19  11   3  19   3   3   9   8  10
8   6   8   9   3  12  18  19   8  11   2
9   8  17  16   0   8   7  17  11  11   0

In [14]: df.sample(3, replace=True)
Out[14]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9
0  13   0  19   5   6  17   5  14   5  15
3   2   6  14  12   1   2  19  16   0  14
3   2   6  14  12   1   2  19  16   0  14

In [15]: df.sample(3, replace=True)
Out[15]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9
9   8  17  16   0   8   7  17  11  11   0
4  17   5   6  13   7  15  10  18  13   8
2  18   3   1  18  12   9  13   2  18  12

In [16]: df.sample(3, replace=True)
Out[16]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9
3   2   6  14  12   1   2  19  16   0  14
8   6   8   9   3  12  18  19   8  11   2
4  17   5   6  13   7  15  10  18  13   8
```

So just replace that loop with:

```
df.sample(71, replace=True).to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Note, this *also* cuts down on I/O overhead!

So, just to do a quick test:

```
In [4]: import time
   ...: start = time.time()
   ...: with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
   ...:     for _ in range(1000):
   ...:         df.sample(71, replace=True).to_csv(f, header=None, index=False)
   ...: stop = time.time()
   ...:

In [5]: stop - start
Out[5]: 0.789172887802124
```

So, extrapolating linearly, I'd gesstimate 1,000,000 times would take about:

```
In [8]: (stop - start) * 1000
Out[8]: 789.172887802124
```

Seconds, so a little over 10 minutes

```
In [10]: !wc -l test.csv
   71000 test.csv
```

#### Edit to add a more valid approach

So, create an array that maps to indicies in the data-frame:

```
size = df.end.max()

nucleotide_array = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int) # this could get out of hand without being careful of our size

for row in df.itertuples(): # might be alittle slow, but its a one-time upfront cost
    i = row.start - 1
    j = row.end
    nucleotide_array[i:j] = row.Index

# sampling scheme:
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(1000): # how ever many experiments
        snps = np.random.choice(nucleotide_array, 71, replace=True)
        df.loc[snps].to_csv(f, header=None, index=False)
```

Note the above is a quick sketch, haven't really tested it out. It makes assumptions, but I think they hold and anyway, you could easily munge your df so it will work.